# CGContextRef draw lines and points,how to clear screen?

Tags: ios, cgcontextref

I using CGContextRef to draw lines and points in a subview, then i want to redraw. How to clear screen in subview? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
 CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
```